# ffmpeg - transpose filter makes output file larger

Tags: ffmpeg

I used the command below (which I found on this site) to flip a video that was taken *upside-down* back *right side up*.

```
$ ffmpeg -i in_file.mp4 -vf "transpose=2,transpose=2" out_file.mp4
```

My issue is this: `out_file.mp4` is 50% larger (in GB) than `in_file.mp4`.

Is this normal?

Comment: You'll have to provide the complete console output from your command to see if there is an obvious reason. Even better if you can also provide a link to `in_file.mp4`. Otherwise we can only guess.

Comment: in_file.mp4 is 3.8GB so the output was an encyclopedia-set long.  Great tip though, I will start teeing the output it to a file.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. Whatever was used to encode the original is more efficient than ffmpeg.  You may eventually thorough careful tuning get back to the original file size.

Think about what's going on.

1. turn the mp4 stream into a stream of raw frames
2. transpose
3. turn the stream of raw frames back into mp4

It's entirely probable (depending on where the source came from) that you would see different output.

Now, if you do the same trick with your output, it should be similar in size.

Comment: I wouldn't call it "more efficient" because that would be an unfair comparison. `ffmpeg` has to re-encode an already lossy source, possibly with visible compression artifacts which affect compressibility: as they are now part of the actual image bits will be wasted by the encoder because it will attempt to preserve these as normal details. Also, it is unknown which encoder was used. If the OP used `mpeg4` instead of `libx264` that could account for much of the difference. Then there's the audio as well, possibly.

Comment: Assuming a regular build, the OP's command invoked x264 to re-encode. x264 is pretty much the most efficient H.264 encoder. With the OP's command, CRF 23 and preset medium is automatically chosen. The original may have higher values for CRF (or lower for bitrate) and a slower preset.